# jQuery - run a function when focusing on a input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, input

I have a text input field, on which when you click a json request fires off, and some data gets retrieved.

```
$("input").focus(function(){
 var thefield = $(this);
 $.getJSON("http://www.blabla.com/bla",
    function(data){
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));  
          thefield.val('blabla');
    }
   );  
});
```

How can I do so this request only gets to run once and not every time I focus on the text field? But I still want `data` to be available when I focus the 2nd, 3rd time etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('input').one('focus', function() {
    // load data using ajax
    $(this).data('ajax-data', data);
});
$('input').focus(function() { $(this).val($(this).data('ajax-data')); });
```

Comment: +1, for the easiest jQuery approach (API reference for [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)), although you could, in a regular click-handler simply call [`unbind('click')`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) (but `one()` is **way** easier and more concise)... =)

Comment: +1, but I prefer wrapping your approach in one bind method and simply check the if `data` is set or not

Comment: @ifaour, I totally agree. I've done something similar in my last code snippet to show that even this code can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Assign another function on the first click or store some value in alt attribute indicating whether you need to fire a request or not

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
//have this line outside any function to make it global:
var _globalData = "";

$("input").focus(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("focused") == "1") {
        alert("already focused before, data is: " + _globalData);
    }
    else {
        var thefield = $(this);
        $.getJSON("http://www.blabla.com/bla",
        function(data) {
            _globalData = JSON.stringify(data);
            alert(_globalData);  
            thefield.val('blabla');
            thefield.attr('focused', '1');
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: @ShadowWizard: `focused` ? are you creating a custom attribute to achieve this?

Comment: @ifaour yes indeed, used to do that for years with pure JavaScript, though it's probably better if I'll start using the jQuery `data` instead..

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, or just compare `$(this)[0]` to `document.activeElement`. And your example will share the same data over all input elements, and I'm not sure that's what he want.

Comment: @Marcus I assume either he has only one text box or the `$("input")` is just an example and in the real code there's `$("#txtMyBox")` so that shouldn't be a problem. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, fair point. One thing I've learnt from this place however, is to never assume anything ;)

Comment: @Marcus - yep, same here.. but sometimes I can't resist the urge. :P

Answer (score 1):

If your `input` elements do not share the same data do this:

```
function loadData(field) {
    $.getJSON("http://www.blabla.com/bla",
        function(response){
            field.data("ajax-data", response).val(response);
        }
    );
};

$("input").focus(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data("ajax-data")) {
        $(this).val($this.data("ajax-data"));
    } else {
        loadData($this);
    }
});
```

If they do share data, it's nearly the same code but with a shared variable instead of using `data`.

```
var data = null;

function loadData(field) {
    $.getJSON("http://www.blabla.com/bla",
        function(response){
            data = response;
            field.val(response);
        }
    );
};

$("input").focus(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if (data) {
        $(this).val(data);
    } else {
        loadData($this);
    }
});
```

You can also create a small jQuery plugin to handle any of the above scenarios, and that also support multiple events:

```
(function($){

    $.fn.loadInputData = function(options){

        var defaults = {
            url: "http://www.blabla.com/bla",
            events: "focus",
            sharedData: false
        };
        var _data = null;

        options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        function loadData(field){
            $.getJSON(options.url,
                function(response){
                    if (options.sharedData) {
                        _data = response;
                    } else {
                        field.data("ajax-data", response);
                    }
                    field.val(response);
                }
            );
        }

        return this.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.bind(options.events, function(){
                if ((options.sharedData && !_data) ||
                    (!options.sharedData && !$this.data("ajax-data")) {
                    loadData($this);
                } else {
                    $this.val(options.sharedData ? _data : $this.data("ajax-data"));
                }
            });
        })
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage for this plugin would be:

```
$("input").loadInputData({ sharedData: true });
```

And just for the kicks, an improved version of the accepted answer:

```
$('input').one('focus', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.getJSON("http://www.blabla.com/bla",
        function(response){
            $this.data("ajax-data", response).val(response);
        }
    );
    $this.focus(function() { $this.val($this.data('ajax-data')); });
});
```